# How to specify defaults for SwaggerResponse and SwaggerResponseExample?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, asp.net-core-6.0

Is there a way to specify the default response example in Swagger similar to the [ProducesDefaultResponseType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesdefaultresponsetypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) like this:

```
[ProducesDefaultResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails))]
```

The Swagger attributes only seem to take the explicitly defined HTTP status codes:

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorExample), Description = "Error details")]
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, typeof(ErrorExample))]
```

Is there a way to get Swagger recognize defaults instead of copying the same information for every HTTP response code?

Comment: sounds like you have maybe more than say 10 response codes in mind? :P

Comment: are annotations the only way to specify response types,  mapped with HttpStatusCodes?

Comment: I would suggest you check the `Default Response` section in [this link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/). See whether it helps to get the helpful information.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks, but I do not see how this spec would be implemented is SwaggerResponse attributes. They seem to always require an integer value for an HTTP status code. Don't see any versions that would take a default.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I think the question is *how* to do this in Swashbuckle.